# How to Uninstall the Ubuntu SDK?

Tags: software-installation, python, uninstall, ubuntu-sdk

After Installing the Ubuntu SDK v1.009 on ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, the computer started behaving in a very unstable manner. Also note that Installing the Ubuntu SDK also installs a lot of test libraries over the stable ones. I wanted to know if there is any way to uninstall the SDK **without reinstalling Ubuntu**. I also want to replace the installed, unstable libraries with the latest stable ones.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: To remove SDK, Click packages, and chroot builds see: [Remove Ubuntu SDK and Click Packages](http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/remove-ubuntu-sdk-click-packages/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can remove **Ubuntu-SDK** without re-installing Ubuntu. Once it is removed, you can also remove all library files associated with it.

- Run following commands in series:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntu-sdk
  $ sudo apt-get --purge remove ubuntu-sdk
  $ sudo apt-get autoclean
  $ sudo apt-get autoremove
  $ sudo apt-get -f install
  ```
- Above commands will remove Ubuntu-SDK from your system. If you get any error after any command, just edit your question and paste the result. Reply for further assistance.

Comment: By the way, there is a _**lot**_ of other stuff needed to **completely** remove the betas. It's a difficult task, as one has to boot into text mode, use `dpkg --list | grep ii | grep test`, remove all the printed packages, remove the PPA and reinstall all the affected packages. So, Do **Not** install The Ubuntu SDK unless you are really, really sure you will stick with it. For 12.04 LTS, it installs too many unstable packages (about 110, When i Installed It) so the entire Operating System Lost It's Balance. However, it does not cause the same issues when I Installed it in Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: I did the above and I still have /var/lib/schroot, /var/lib/schroot/chroots with gigabytes worth of ubuntu-sdk stuff. Eg /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-amd64